Finite group is Dedekind iff for every irrep, every element acts as identity or has all eigenvalues $\ne 1$
Consider the following claim: a finite group $G$ is Dedekind $\iff$ for every irrep $\rho$, and every $g \in G$, $\rho(g)$ either is identity matrix or has all eigenvalues $\ne 1$.
Is this claim true?
Recall that finite Dedekind groups are abelian or $Q_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_2^t \times \mathbb{Z}_m$ for odd $m$, integer $t$, $Q_8$ the quaternion group.
Dedekind $\implies$ for every irrep $\rho$, and every $g \in G$, $\rho(g)$ either is identity matrix or has all eigenvalues $\ne 1$ holds by inspection.
So the question is whether $\impliedby$ holds.

Could you remind us of the definition of "Dedekind group"?

The definition you wrote does not agree with wikipedia (a finite abelian group of odd order need not be cyclic).

The condition can be restated as: for every $g$ and $\rho$, the subspace $\mathrm{Ker}(\rho(g)-1)$ is a subrepresentation.
If $G$ is Dedekind (meaning that every subgroup is normal, or equivalently that every cyclic subgroup is normal), then $\langle g\rangle$ being normal, the result follows (no need to use inspection).
Conversely, suppose that $\mathrm{Ker}(\lambda(g)-1)$ is a subrepresentation for $\lambda$ the left regular representation. This kernel is the set $U_g$ of functions that are left $\langle g\rangle$-invariant, and we readily see that for $h\in G$, $hU_g=U_{hgh^{-1}}$, and $U_g=U_{g'}$ iff $\langle g\rangle =\langle g'\rangle$. So the condition that $U_g$ is a subrepresentation means that $\langle g\rangle$ is normal. If this is true for every $g$, this means that $G$ is Dedekind.

Clifford's Theorem is relevant here and  might be illuminating.

@GeoffRobinson Pointer? The Wikipedia reference for Clifford's theorem seems unrelated. [But well "illuminating": does this straightforward proof really seem obscure?]

No, your proof is fine and certainly not obscure,  I intended no criticism of it, rather the opposite, since I updated it. To me Clifford's  Theorem provides a natural explanation for the fact that that a normal subgroup with any fixed point in an irreducible representation  acts trivially,  but it is true that CT might be considered unnecessary machinery to prove that particular fact. I have never looked at the Wikid

....Wikipedia page for CT, but for me CT is an indispensable tool in representatio  theory- that may be a matter of taste. -I meant up voted it that was an auto text error.

@GeoffRobinson I finally found the link Clifford theory. The theorem assumes $N$ normal so indeed reproves the most trivial implication (with a far-reaching generalization).
